# How to get the coordinates of an image using SFML?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sfml

I am programming a car racing game, and I came to the stage of placing obstacles on the road.

To place each one of them in the right position, I chose to write the coordinates that I get by using this function:

`Mouse::getPosition(RenderWindow)`

The problem is that the whole image of the road is invisible, and you can see the other parts only when the car moves,while the function `getPosition()` returns coordinates of the window and not those of the image.

Is there **any** function or method to convert them?

Comment: If you know your image offset related to screen you can easily calculate position on the map knowing screen coordinates.

Comment: can you explain more? Thanks

Comment: I don't know much about SFML. You say that the whole image is not visible? How do you render it, to which coordinates? Take a piece of paper, draw large rectangle. Then within this rectangle draw smaller one. Large one is your map, small is your screen.

Comment: To those voting for close - this is perfectly valid and specific question, don't abuse close button. It may require clarification but there are no reasons to close it.

Comment: It may seem a very simple solution but I think that the easiest method will be by showing the whole road :) Thank you andrey.And for those who vote for close if you need any clarification ask me I will be glad to answer.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem, thus my guess is that you want to convert screen coordinates to world coordinates which is explained in the [official tutorials](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/graphics-view.php#coordinates-conversions), i.e. use the render window's [mapPixelToCoords](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3.1/classsf_1_1RenderTarget.php#a46eb08f775dd1420d6207ea87dde6e54) function.

Comment: Lukas already done thank you :) !

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:To get the current mouse position in the window : 
sf::Vector2i pixelPos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(Window).
And to convert it to world coordinates :
sf::Vector2f worldPos = Window.mapPixelToCoords(pixelPos).
To write the coordinates on the screen:
`cout<<worldPos.x<<worldPos.y<<'\n'`.
Even when the view changes this method will give you the real coordinates of the image.